# Meta sitename or sitename meta

Tags: discussion, meta

Just wondering will the meta SO and SU sites names be changing to the Meta after the sitename, or will the sites in beta be moving to the same format as meta SO and SU. Or will they just stay different

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: @Pekka: as an example, this site used to be called Stack Overflow Meta.

Comment: Like Electronic Gadgets Meta, but it's Meta Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard for per-site metas is to have `Meta` follow the site name: `Super User Meta`, `Web Apps Meta`.

However, Meta Stack Overflow is a special case, being the "national capital" of Stack Exchange (and having been created some time before Stack Exchange existed).

Comment: well meta stackoverflow makes more sense seeing as the address is meta.stackoverflow and meta means about, you don't say stackoverflow about you'd say about stackoverflow.

Comment: But having the meta afterwards makes alphabetical lists easier :)