# Meta title word order different from MSO?

Tags: bug, meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Meta sitename or sitename meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63409/meta-sitename-or-sitename-meta)

Each Stack Exchange site has a meta site, found at `http://meta.stackexchangesite.com/`, but is named in the window title bar as `Stack Exchange Site Meta`, for example `Super User Meta`, or `Web Apps Meta`.

**However,** Meta Stack Overflow seems to be the exception, the title bar says `Meta Stack Overflow`...

*Why are they different?*

and, *should one scenario or the other be changed?*

Comment: The question was, "Why Meta be different, Jack?" The answer is, "Because it is, Slim." That it's tagged a bug is an oversight @jer